# does ActiveXObject work in Windows 8 store apps developed using HTML5 and Javascript

Tags: html, activex, winjs, activexobject

I am developing Win8 store app using HTML5 and JavaScript. I need to integrate Lync with the app. So I have tried a snipped which enables lync integration with browser.

```
var nameCtrl = new ActiveXObject('Name.NameCtrl.1');
```

This works fine for me in IE but the same code gives me below error when placed in win8 store app.

#### Automation server can't create object

Answer (score 0):

No. ActiveX does not run inside a Windows Store app. It just would be too easy to insert malware that way.

Comment: ohh! thanks for the info. 
Is there any way I could integrate Microsoft Lync to the windows store app using winjs?

Comment: I don't think it would be possible to integrate directly. You might be able to use a build a WCF service and use lync on a server to which you communicate from your app, but I'm not sure it'll work.